# Maximal exact match with allowing a certain number of mismaches

Tags: string, algorithm, substring, intervals

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm for this problem.

1.Two strings (m,n) are given and the length of the first one is relatively very smaller than the second one (the first is usually used as query with length 100 and the second one can be 100,000,000 character.

2.all maximal exact matches of the first string in the second one is also given as a vector of intervals in two strings. the chance of having a multiple occurrence of a sub string of m in n increases with decreasing the size of that sub string.

The problem is finding the biggest common interval in both m and n allowing certain number of mismatches like p.

example in the picture[image]

Comment: you need to post example tests

Comment: By "biggest common interval", what do you mean? And what counts as a mismatch?

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan example is provided now

Comment: @SanjayManohar the biggest common interval is the interval which exist in two strings, so its common and mismatch means if you have A in one string it would be B in the second. , please have a look to the example

Comment: OK Thanks I think I understand. I've tried what I think to be the most efficient solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. 
I suppose there are already solutions to this from genetics literature, but I don't know them. So here's an attempt:

We certainly need to slide B over A, so let's start with

```
// let's keep track of best match so far
longestRegionLen   = -1 
longestRegionPos   = -1 // position within A of best match start

for i = 0 to len(A):


end
```

Now, we'll need to compare the whole of B against the corresponding region of A. But if M mismatches are permitted, we only need to know the last M+1 mismatch locations, in order to know how long our segment of "nearly-match" is. So, within this loop:

```
  // keep track of last M+1 nonmatches
  lastNonMatch       = int[M+1]   // initialise values to 0
  for j = 0 to len(B):
     match =   A[i+j] == B[j]
     if not match:
        lastNonMatch[0 to M-1] = lastNonMatch[1 to M]
        lastNonMatch[M] = j
        // how long since the nonmatch M nonmatches ago?
        // are we better than the previous one?
        if j-lastNonMatch[0] > longestRegion:
           longestRegionLen = j-lastNonMatch[0]
           longestRegionPos = i+j
  end
```

I haven't tested the algorithm, but it looks like it will be O(N*M). So what's happening is

```
ABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDA
       DACCDABBDABDDACCDABDDAB
         *    *   *  *    *
       01234567890123456789012
       i       
                     j
                     ^
                     |
```

nonmatch here. If `M==3`, then 
`lastNonMatch` buffer contains `[ 0 2 7 11 ]`

and at this point, `j==14`, and we make `lastNonMatch` `[2 7 11 14]`, and we find that the distance from `j` to `2` is large (12), so we call this the largest region that contains 3 mismatches.

I can't think of a way to make this faster, but perhaps someone cleverer will visit your question soon?